# Value of $total not being set inside lumen collection map function

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, php-closures

I have a lumen collection object for my order and use map function to iterate over it and do some logic. I also need the total value of the order which is calculated using `quantity * price`. But the variable that is responsible for holding the total value is always `0`.

```
$total = 0;
$items = Cart_Item::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
$items = $items->map(function ($item, $key) use ($order, $total) {
    $product = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->first();
    $order_item = new Order_Item();
    $order_item->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_item->product_id = $item->product_id;
    $order_item->quantity = $item->quantity;
    $order_item->price = $product->GetPrice->price;
    $order_item->save();
    $total = $total + ($order_item->quantity * $order_item->price);
});
```

No matter what I do, the `$total` always returns `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of your [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) is not that of the entire file, but it's limited only to what's between the `{}` tags.

The `use`d variables are *copied* into the function scope.

One solution would be to make `$total` a global variable:

```
$total = 0;
$items = Cart_Item::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
$items = $items->map(function ($item, $key) use ($order, $total) {
    $product = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->first();
    $order_item = new Order_Item();
    $order_item->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_item->product_id = $item->product_id;
    $order_item->quantity = $item->quantity;
    $order_item->price = $product->GetPrice->price;
    $order_item->save();

    global $total;
    $total = $total + ($order_item->quantity * $order_item->price);
});
```

Another is to pass global as a reference `&$total` like so:

```
$total = 0;
$items = Cart_Item::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
$items = $items->map(function ($item, $key) use ($order, &$total) {
    $product = Product::where('id', $item->product_id)->first();
    $order_item = new Order_Item();
    $order_item->order_id = $order->id;
    $order_item->product_id = $item->product_id;
    $order_item->quantity = $item->quantity;
    $order_item->price = $product->GetPrice->price;
    $order_item->save();

    $total = $total + ($order_item->quantity * $order_item->price);
});
```